# How can I get to the last wave of the pumpkin Moon in terraria 1.2.3 console?

Tags: terraria-console

I wanted to challenge the Pumpkin Moon. I keep getting to Wave 8 and the night ends. The problem might be that I'm not killing them fast enough. I tried an arena but it either fails, kills me, or is very slow. I have a lot of really good Items. I currently wear Dragon Armour, Spectral Armour and Titan Armour. If that makes a difference. I got the Horsemans Blade. I was able to get Red's Wings before they updated it. How do I get to wave 15 of the pumpkin moon? What strategy do I use?

Comment: Also I have really good stuff like the Razorpine from when I fought the Frost Moon.

Comment: He's not asking about *surviving* the Pumpkin moon; he can do that no problem.  It's the fact he can't do enough damage to make it through the waves.  I think it's different enough to allow.

Comment: See [Should I be setting up an arena to defeat the pumpkin moon?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/219826/) and [What gear should I have to survive the pumpkin moon?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190455/).

Comment: Im not asking how to Survive the pumpkin moon, nor am I asking for an arena. I am asking on how I would go through the waves faster.